# Apache wildcard at domain level

Tags: apache, subdomain, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain, wildcard-mapping

I have few sites, and they all have identical setup on a single server. Now, instead of the separate configuration file for each of them in sites-enabled directory, I want to have a common file.

Idea is this:

www.abc.com  should have  /var/www/abc    as DocumentRoot,
www.xyz.com  should have /var/www/xyz  as DocumentRoot, etc.

All other parameteres like log files, contact emails etc should also have identical setup (abc.com should have contact@abc.com as admin email, xyz.com should have contact@xyz.com as admin email etc).

I couldnt find any tutorial on how to backreference wildcards,  etc.

regards,

JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha. Found the solution.   VirtualDocumentRoot is the answer.

A single line like:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0
```

does the job. Havent really figured the logs stuff but should be similar and easy.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/182929/wildcard-subdomain-directory-names for a nice related thread.

You gotta enable vhost_alias module for this.  (`sudo a2enmod vhost_alias` on ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks Jeff for "correcting" the link.  Its surprising to know that that thread was originally on SO.